# Is there a good and easy way to find algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

I'm mainly a selftought I started studying computer science half a year ago.

Before studying, I genneraly just tried to think of an algorithm to do the tasks I needed to be done - with sorting algorithms for example this was quite easy (they might not have been super efficient, but they did good enough). But sometimes I really struggled to come up with algorithms for quite typical problems:

One example for this is triangulation.
The problem is: I didn't know it was called like that. Quite a few hours later I finally found out about delauney triangulation, and all my problems where immediately solved.

Also in computer science I'm learning about a lot of specific algorithms, but my question is:

Is there a way to learn about all these "important" algorithms, maybe by type or something simular? Or is the only good way to keep studying and hope they come my way at some point?

Comment: This question may be too broad for SO.  Have you tried searching for book titles with the word "algorithms" in them?  It is a very broad subject, but [Knuth](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=wzteWpegGILWjwPA64GwBw&q=knuth+the+art+of+computer+programming&oq=knuth&gs_l=psy-ab.1.9.0l10.452.2122.0.8998.5.5.0.0.0.0.69.280.5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.279...46j0i131k1j0i3k1j0i46k1.0.4EUwAwTogkk) covers the essential core set.  That reference probably dates me, I am sure there must be more modern treatises on subject today.

Comment: This is an entirely reasonable question -- most of us have our own re-invention stories (with me it's [skiplists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)) because we didn't know something already existed -- but unfortunately it doesn't work well as a _StackOverflow_ question, where we prefer to aim at concrete problems.

Comment: If a few google searches don't satisfy, you can always ask a specific question in the algorithm tag on SO.  If it doesn't sound like homework/contest and you don't add any other tags, then responders will usually recognize that your question is a reasonable thing to ask before writing any code.